# регулярные выражения дата

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Зайти строки, соответствующие шаблону, 
который задает дату от 1 января 1900 до 31 декабря 2017: YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM (: SS) 
Пример: 2012-09-18 12:10 - подходит 
2019-10-03 22:15 - не подходит
Напишите регулярные выражения

Comment: И где же ВАШИ попытки решить задачу? Для/за Вас тут никто делать не станет.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Это должно работать:

```
(19\d\d|200\d|201[0-7])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\s([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)(:([0-5]\d))?
```

[демо](https://regex101.com/r/iqVQT3/2)

Не знает, сколько дней у каждого месяца, не говоря уже о високосных годах ... Для вдохновения, посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: Чё тут про високосные думать - вон, `2000-99-99 99:99` мало похоже на валидную дату, а тест проходит.